# PHP parse field and calculate difference

Tags: php, evaluate

Can someone provide a way to parse a field with a format like the following and take the difference between the two values between the colons.

```
bot1:11874-12227:top
```

For example, the resultant field would be equal to 12227-11874 = 353.

I think something like a scan by delimiter and then eval the negative of the difference.

Comment: Where is the code you tried to write ?

Comment: this regexp is enough `/:(\d+)-(\d+):/`

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "bot1:11874-12227:top";
$parts = explode(":", $string);
$numbers = explode("-", $parts[1]);
$difference = (($numbers[1] - $numbers[0]) > 0) ? $numbers[1] - $numbers[0] : $numbers[0] - $numbers[1];

echo $difference;
```

Comment: @gnagy. That last part $difference looks pretty complicated. Let me stare at it for a couple minutes and search on how to interpret. Thanks again!

Comment: The last part is basically an if statement, if your second number is bigger than the first, return their difference that way (second - first), otherwise return first - second. If you're 100% sure the second number is always bigger, you can just write $difference = $numbers[1] - $numbers[0]

Comment: Last part could be much simplified as `$difference = abs($numbers[1] - $numbers[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Easy just use a regex with `preg_match`:

```
$string = 'bot1:11874-12227:top';

preg_match("#[A-Za-z]+[0-9]?:([0-9]+)([-|+|*|//])([0-9]+):[A-Za-z]+#", $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

The results would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bot1:11874-12227:top
    [1] => 11874
    [2] => -
    [3] => 12227
)
```

Then just do the following for the math:

```
echo abs($matches[1] - $matches[3]);
```

Now, note how `$matches[2]` matches the mathematical operator? Well, why not make use of that to do the following with [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/create_function):

```
$string_to_math_results = create_function("", "return ($matches[1] $matches[2] $matches[3]);" );

echo abs($string_to_math_results());
```

So bring it all together like this. Now you can not only parse the values out of the string, but perform basic calculations based on the value in the strings:

```
$string = 'bot1:11874-12227:top';

preg_match("#[A-Za-z]+[0-9]?:([0-9]+)([-|+|*|//])([0-9]+):[A-Za-z]+#", $string, $matches);

$string_to_math_results = create_function("", "return ($matches[1] - $matches[3]);" );

echo abs($string_to_math_results());
```

Comment: this is enough `/:(\d+)-(\d+):/`

Comment: go as you like friend :)